# Higher equivariance

Tags: reference-request, homotopy-theory, kt.k-theory-and-homology

The Atiyah-Segal completion theorem states that $K(BG) = \mathrm{Rep}(G) = K_G(*)$, when the left hand side is completed with respect to the augmentation ideal. In some sense, $G$-equivariant $K$-theory only "sees" the fundamental groupoid.

Ravenel-Wilson and Eric made this precise: Morava $K$-theory and $E$-theory only detect nontrivial $K(Z,q)$ for $q \leq n+1$ and $K(Z/p^k,q)$ for $q \leq n$. If $X$ is a space with homotopy groups concentrated in dimensions $0$ and $1$, both of which are finite, one should be able to define "$X$-equivariant $K$-theory".

More generally, if $E$ is a $K(n)$-local spectrum (maybe $L_n$-local?), we should be able to define "$X$-equivariant $E$-cohomology" if $X$ is a space with homotopy groups concentrated in dimensions $\leq n$. This should somehow relate to the whole idea of "twisting" Morava $K$- and $E$-theory.

Is there any work regarding this matter?

Comment: Sections 5.1 and 5.4 of Lurie's survey on elliptic cohomology discuss this, but as far as I'm aware the details have not yet appeared: https://www.math.ias.edu/~lurie/papers/survey.pdf. The ongoing series of preprints Elliptic Cohomology I-III by Lurie already covers much of the survey, however.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the reference!